# Show/Hide Date & Time on Lock Screen During Sleep Focus

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-lock

This video shows how to show/hide time on iPhone: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vOdZk3ksXj0&t=7s&pp=2AEHkAIB

But I do not have the 'Show time' button in the sleep focus. I'm on an iPhone 12 running iOS 15. How come I do not have option to hide time on lock screen?

Comment: This option shows fine for me on my iPhone 11. Can you add a screenshot please?

Comment: Deleted focus and set it up again, and option has appeared